# iMessage sent to one phone is going to another phone instead

Tags: messages

My brother in laws daughter is intercepting all his iMessages on her iPhone. Someone sends him an iMessage and instead of going to his phone, it goes to hers???? This started right after she updated his phone and used her info and wifi. Plain texts still go to him

Comment: How are those iPhones linked?

Answer (score 1):

Do they, somehow, use the same Apple ID? If so, the phone number has paired to the Apple ID, and every iMessage will notify the most active device (that is, the daughter in this case) before pinging the others.

As some would say, it's not a bug. It's a feature. I have a few solutions for your brother in law:

### If the Apple ID belongs to the daughter

You said:

> she updated his phone and used her info

If the father has the daughter's Apple ID logged in on his iPhone, just go to `Settings :: Messages :: Receive at` on the father's iPhone and log in with the right Apple ID.

### If the Apple ID is the father's one

If both the daughter and the father are logged in to the father's Apple ID, you have the following options:

#### Get the daughter a personal iCloud account

As the daughter already has an iPhone, I suggest your brother in law creates an account for her. If they use a version older than iOS 8, they can go to `Settings :: Messages` and create an Apple ID from there that will just be used for iMessage and FaceTime. She will still be able to download apps from your brother in law account. Otherwise, if they use iOS 8, they can create a new child account that will be used for all services, including the App Store, but use the same credit card (the daughter will have to send requests to buy)

#### Disable the feature

If they have to keep the same iTunes account, you can go to `Settings :: Messages :: Receive at` on the daughter's iPhone, and uncheck your brother-in-law phone number. This way, she won't receive his iMessages anymore.